# MSTest - How to limit test result folders

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

Every time an MSTest runs it creates a new time stamped folder inside of `TestResults`. This can result in many files/folders that take up hard drive space.

Is there a way to configure MSTest to overwrite the contents of the `TestResults` folder so that is only contains results from the most recent run?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can limit the number of stored test-runs to 1, which should meet your requirements.

[MSDN have an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514184%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on how to achieve this:

- In Visual Studio, click **Options** on the **Tools** menu.
- The Options dialog box appears.
- Expand **Test Tools** or **Web Performance Test Tools** and click **Test Execution**
- Under Test Results Management, select the number of test runs to
  keep.
- Click OK.
  [image]

Comment: This option is not available in VS2012 - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788387/visual-studio-2012-limit-number-of-old-test-result-option - does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: @LasseChristiansen-sw_lasse it's also not available in VS2013

Comment: @LasseChristiansen-sw_lasse here's a hacky workaround.  Set this as your post-build event in your test project `rmdir /S /Q $(SolutionDir)TestResults`  Using this, there should never be more than one test run folder which will contain the most recent test run files.